# Terraform pass variables to a child module

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass a variable from the `root module` to a `child module` with the following syntax:

**main.tf:**

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 1.11"
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
  region     = "${var.aws_region}"
}

module "iam" {
  account_id = "${var.account_id}"
  source = "./modules/iam"
}

 * account_id value is stored on variables.tf in the root folder
```

**/modules/iam/iam.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "myName" {
    name       = "myName"
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:policy/myName" <-- doesnt work
    groups     = []
    users      = []
    roles      = []
}
```

when I try to access within the module to `account_id` an error is thrown.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to declare any variables that a module uses at the module level itself:

```
variable "account_id" {
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "myName" {
    name       = "myName"
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:policy/myName"
    groups     = []
    users      = []
    roles      = []
}
```

Comment: Correct, though it would be best to follow the approach the OP is already using: a dedicated variables.tf file which holds all variables and its defaults.

Comment: To clarify, declaring the variable here inherits the value of the variable with the same name from the parent module?

Comment: @ErikMaldonado unless something has changed in the newer versions (I’ve not been involved with TF for a little while), no. Note in the OP the variable is being passed in when the module is used. Without this additional declaration, that doesn’t work by itself. Likewise not passing it in as per the OP will just use the default declared in the module version of the variable if it has one, otherwise I think it throws an error.

Answer (score 7):

James is correct but his syntax will work just for string variables. With others you have to specify the 'blank default':

```
variable "passed_list_var" {
    default = []
}

variable "passed_map_var" {
    default = {}
}
```

Comment: just want to add a comment to thank [ondrej-bardon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10971917/ondrej-bardon) as this has helped me fix an issue that has been plaguing me for a couple of days.